# Insert new value to table C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying to add new records to my table `tblEmployee`. This is my code:

```
        cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(daEmp);

        DataRow dRow = dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].NewRow();
        dRow["EmployeeID"] = txtID.Text;
        dRow["Lname"] = txtLname.Text;
        dRow["Fname"] = txtFname.Text;
        dRow["Mname"] = txtMname.Text;
        dRow["Address"] = txtAddress.Text;
        dRow["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
        dRow["Phone"] = Convert.ToInt64(txtPhone.Text);
        dRow["Jobtitle"] = txtJobtitle.Text;
        dRow["Salary"] = txtSalary.Text;
        dRow["DeptID"] = drpDepartments.SelectedValue;

        dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Rows.Add(dRow);
        daEmp.Update(dsEmp, "tblEmployee");
        dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].AcceptChanges();
```

I'm getting this error message on this line: `dRow["Phone"] = txtPhone;`. It says `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox> in Phone Column.  Expected type is Int64.`

The code for the textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

The datatype of `Phone` column on my database is int but I changed it to bigint and still getting the same error. What seems to be the problem?

By the way I'm using C# ASP.NET.

Comment: try to change it to string and use `textbox.Text` to get the value. Or if you still want phone as `int` use `Convert.ToInt64` on the `txtPhone.Text`

Comment: Another error `Column 'EmployeeID' does not allow nulls.` Error on this line `dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Rows.Add(dRow);`

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! Everything is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Phone` field is a number field, then you should:

```
dRow["Phone"] = Convert.ToInt64(txtPhone.Text);
```

Comment: How about for money datatype what should I use?

Comment: Another error `Column 'EmployeeID' does not allow nulls.` Error on this line `dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Rows.Add(dRow);`

Comment: You need to set `dRow["EmployeeID"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use txtPhone.Text to get the value in the textbox instead of the textbox object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `txtPhone.Text` to assign the value of the Phone Number.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(daEmp);

        DataRow dRow = dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].NewRow();
        dRow["Lname"] = txtLname.Text;
        dRow["Fname"] = txtFname.Text;
        dRow["Mname"] = txtMname.Text;
        dRow["Address"] = txtAddress.Text;
        dRow["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
        dRow["Phone"] = txtPhone.Text;
        dRow["Jobtitle"] = txtJobtitle.Text;
        dRow["Salary"] = txtSalary.Text;
        dRow["DepartmentID"] = drpDepartments.SelectedValue;

        dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Rows.Add(dRow);
        daEmp.Update(dsEmp, "tblEmployee");
        dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].AcceptChanges();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all use the `.Text` property everywhere and for phone cast it is integer

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(daEmp);

    DataRow dRow = dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].NewRow();
    dRow["Lname"] = txtLname.Text;
    dRow["Fname"] = txtFname.Text;
    dRow["Mname"] = txtMname.Text;
    dRow["Address"] = txtAddress.Text;
    dRow["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
    dRow["Phone"] = Convert.ToInt32(txtPhone.Text);
    dRow["Jobtitle"] = txtJobtitle.Text;
    dRow["Salary"] = txtSalary.Text;
    dRow["DepartmentID"] = drpDepartments.SelectedValue;
    dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Rows.Add(dRow);
    daEmp.Update(dsEmp, "tblEmployee");
    dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].AcceptChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast your phone to text by adding txtPhone.text. Actually you should do it for all fields value from webforms and also need to proper validation for every form fields it is a good practice..